# Having issues with a user defined arrays program in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write a program that writes a program that uses the heap to store an array. I have a problem where the program will crash after successfully running it. I also have some small aesthetic problems, the element needs to start at 1 and no comma on the last number that is printed. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int* num_elements;
    num_elements = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

    printf("How many int elements will you enter?");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("\n");

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: ", k);
        scanf("%d", &num_elements[k]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("The Array stores the following values: \n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", num_elements[j]);
    }

    printf("\n");    
    free(num_elements);    
    num_elements = 0;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PinkPanther11222: He told you wrong then. Initialisation is done with the definition (note it includes "initial"). Anything else is not an initialisation, but an assignment. (it is good practice for beginners on PC, though)

Comment: @Olaf Thank you, I will remember that for future reference

Comment: Do you really have to write a program that writes a program (i.e. a code generator) -- or is it enough to just write a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case user enters a value more than 3, you'll end up using out of bound memory. As you're using dynamic memory allocation, make the best of it. Ask the value of `size` from the user and then, use it to call `malloc()` like

```
int* num_elements;

printf("How many int elements will you enter?");
scanf("%d", &size);

num_elements = malloc(size * sizeof *num_elements);
```

Then, to print the element numbering from `1`, you can write it like

```
printf("Element %d: ", k+1);
```

That said,

1. [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. Always check the return value of `malloc()` for success before using.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My code is working now. I am fairly new to C, so I will look at that discussion.